# Drawing contour trees in vtk

Tags: visualization, vtk

Does VTK provide any classes about contour tree related implementations? I've searched for it but I didn't find anything, is there a way of implementing a contour tree visualization in VTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VTK provides an [implementation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkReebGraph.html#details) of Reeb graphs. Contour trees are just special cases of Reeb graphs for simply connected domains, so you can consider this as an implementation of CT-s.